# Leaflet fitBounds Starting Position

Tags: javascript, leaflet, csv, position

I am creating a Leaflet application that uses the code from the [Simple CSV template](https://github.com/perrygeo/leaflet-simple-csv) to set the bounds of the map to the selected markers.

The issue I have is that I want to set a `start` position that isn't the bounds of all of my markers. I would also like the map to return to this `start` position once the `clear` function is initiated as well.

Some of the key sections of code can be seen below but the repository is available by the link above.

```
var addCsvMarkers = function() {
hits = 0;
total = 0;
filterString = document.getElementById('filter-string').value;

if (filterString) {
    $("#clear").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#clear").fadeOut();
}

map.removeLayer(markers);
points.clearLayers();

markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(clusterOptions);
points.addData(dataCsv);
markers.addLayer(points);

map.addLayer(markers);
try {
    var bounds = markers.getBounds();
    if (bounds) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds, {maxZoom: 15});
    }
} catch(err) {
    // pass
}
if (total > 0) {
    $('#search-results').html("Showing <b>" + hits + "</b> of <b>" + total + "</b> Projects");
}
return false;
};
```

&

```
$("#clear").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $("#filter-string").val("").focus();
    addCsvMarkers();
});
```

EDIT: Is it possible for the `setView` that is called in when defining the map to override the `fitBounds` command?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
zoomControl: false,
minZoom: 3,
maxZoom: 18
}).setView([54.5, -4], 6);
```

Answer (score 3):

Many options here depending on what you are wanting to do exactly.

1. Add a boolean argument to addCsvMarkers that optionally fits the map to the markers

   ```
   function addCsvMarkers(fitBounds) {

       // snip... jumping to the middle... 
       map.addLayer(markers);
       try {
           var bounds = markers.getBounds();
           // check for fitBounds option here
           if (bounds && fitBounds) {
               map.fitBounds(bounds, {maxZoom: 15});
           }
       // ...snip
   }

   // call it like so, to skip fitting bounds on the csv markers:
   addCsvMarkers(false);
   ```
2. As long as your map is in global scope, you can also define a function, e.g. "zoomHome" that returns the map to any view/extent you want:

   ```
   function zoomHome() {
       map.setView([54.5, -4], 6);
   }
   ```

   You can call this when you init the app:

   ```
   // declare map in global scope
   var map; 
   $(document).ready(function() {
       map = L.map('map', {
           zoomControl: false,
           minZoom: 3,
           maxZoom: 18
       });
       // here:
       zoomHome();
   });
   ```

   Or as a part of "clear"

   ```
   $("#clear").click(function(evt){
       evt.preventDefault();
       $("#filter-string").val("").focus();
       addCsvMarkers(false);
       zoomHome();
   });
   ```

Comment: The seconds option works perfectly when using it as part of "clear", however when using it on (document).ready it appears to remove the map as I get `Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined`, i'm guessing this is to do with the map being in global scope?

Comment: check anywhere you are calling "addLayer" on "map"; if this is happening _before_ the Leaflet map object is defined, then map will be undefined. It's all about sequence: 1) load Leaflet library 2) define an empty global map var to hold the map, 3) define the Leaflet map object and init the map, 4) add layers. Any other order will not work (although in fact 1 and 2 are interchangeable)